# SQL Server trigger on table vs trigger on view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers

I am working on a project where my college wants only newly inserted or updated data. It concerns ca. 5 SQL Server tables. Values in many columns could be updated/changed (surname, id, department, exit date, residence, family status, etc)
none of these tables have timestamp or datetime column, when was last change made.

I would like to use triggers (insert and update) to get only newly inserted / updated values.

My question is, is it a good approach? If yes, should I use triggers on original tables or is it better to get data into one view and use triggers on views?

Comment: It depends on your needs

Comment: How could anybody possibly provide an answer to such a vague question? This is too broad, primarily opinion based and is lacking enough detail for an answer. Do you update the tables or a view?

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for your Answer. No, tables are updated by HR  department via their Program,  i have direct access on tables

Comment: If that program updates the tables then putting triggers on a view would be rather pointless wouldn't it? A trigger fires when an event happens on the object it is connect to. So if they update the table then you want to capture that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write your own triggers and tracking tables to keep track of changing data.  SQL Server [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) will do that for you.